# Ajax limiting amount of items returned

Tags: php, ajax

I'm making a AJAX request like this:

```
$("#botao_pesquisar_material").click(function(){
    $(this).attr("disabled", "disabled");
    $("#material").addClass('loading');
    $.ajax({
        url: '{{ URL::base() }}/material/lista_ajax/',
        dataType: 'json',
        cache: false,
        error: function(data)
        {
            console.log(data);
        },
        success: function(data) {
            for(x in data)
            {
                console.log(data[x]);
            }
        }
    });
```

My PHP method is ok because when I access it via URL, it returns me the expected JSON and when I call this on localhost, it works perfectly so it isn't about special characters or something else with the data.

When I run this on my server I have this:

```
GET http://dc.portaldeideias.com.br:8080/sergios/public/material/lista_ajax/?callback=jQuery172007718208665028214_1342725644520&_=1342725649090 500 (Internal Server Error) jquery.js:4
f.support.ajax.f.ajaxTransport.send jquery.js:4
f.extend.ajax jquery.js:4
$.click.$.ajax.url
f.event.dispatch jquery.js:3
f.event.add.h.handle.i
```

Using `console.log(data)` I have the entire JSON response but here is what is really strange:

The `readyState` is `4`

The `responseText` is `[{"attributes":{"pk_a030_id":78,"a030_descricao":"Camur\u00e7a"},"original":{"pk_a030_id":78,"a030_descricao":"Camur\u00e7a"},"relationships":[],"exists":true,"includes":[]}]`

The `statusText` is `Internal Server Error`

So, the requested value is created but I receive a `Internal Server Error`

Comment: What is the actual error in your server's error log?

Comment: does it generates log for ajax calls?

Comment: Yes, of course.  From the point of view of the server, there's not difference in how the call is invoked.

Comment: ok, gonna check that and report back.

Comment: @AleksG I'm using XAMPP, so I came to `apache/logs` and opened the `error.log` but there is no errors referencing my application. Is there another way to check it?

Comment: do you see the 60 colors when you browse there directly? what is the data for row 25? try htmlentities($objeto->a032_descricao)

Comment: @Waygood yes...and if I access the URL via browser it returns the values in the necessary format...so I think there is nothing wrong with `PHP` or `Apache`. I'm gonna print what the method returned and paste here...

Comment: @Waygood gonna trye the `htmlentities` command

Comment: @Waygood same error =/ I have checked each item from my table and there is nothing wrong with characters and there are no accents or any special characters

Comment: You could use json instead of html. See `json_encode` http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php

Comment: Try to set the `dataType` otherwise jQuery tries to guess it.

Comment: The problem is not with the Ajax call, it is with the method I'm calling, when I take it from the generated line on the PHP code it works, any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry for posting this as an answer, but I don't have the required privileges to add this as a comment for your question.

Have you noticed that the URL in the javascript log `http://localhost:8080/sergios/public/material/lista_ajax/` is different than the one provided in your screenshot `http://dc.p[...]s.com.br:8080/sergios/public/material/lista_ajax`?

Could it be the case that you have two different versions of the `lista_ajax` PHP method hosted in two different servers (maybe one remote and the other one local), and that's why it works flawless when seeing it from the browser and has bugs when tested with ajax?

It's also important to notice that if you are browsing a website hosted on a remote server, and the ajax is configured to a `localhost` address, it will do a request for your own  machine, not the remote server (javascript runs in the browser, so `localhost` translates to its own client address).

Maybe this is not the case, but it was worth commenting.

Comment: Now (30 minutes after posting the answer) I do have the privileges to comment, but moving all this text to a comment would be messy (and wouldn't fit in the 600 character limit) .